# angularjs and Parse.com service - firing multiple requests?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I am working on a simple app using parse as a service and angular for the ui.

I am noticing for some reason when making any request to parse, the request fires multiple times. (consistently, 3)

[image]

```
  //controller
     app.controller('adminCtrl', function($scope, $location, healthTrackerFactory){   
      healthTrackerFactory.getUsers().success(function(success) {
        console.log(success)
           $scope.user = success.results;
      }).error(function() {

      });
    });



   //Factory
    healthTracker.factory('healthTrackerFactory', [ '$http', function($http){

      var urlBase = 'https://api.parse.com';
      var healthTrackerFactory = {};

  healthTrackerFactory.getUsers = function(){
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: urlBase + '/1/users',
      headers:  {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'APPID', 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'APIKEY', 'Content-type' : 'application/json'}
    })
  }
 return healthTrackerFactory;               
 }]);
```

When I do a test without angular, the service works correctly, however I am using angular for this project.

Has anyone had any issues using Parse with Angular like this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Javascript SDK or accessing Parse.com through the REST API https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide ? and also can you share the healthTrackerFactory code?

Comment: @JideobiBenedineOfomah Using the REST API.  I just included my factory code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think every time Angular digest runs, current controller is kinda refreshed, move the call to the factory into a function called via button click, if you must call it without being triggered by a user and be used in the controller, move it to the $state transition section.

```
$stateProvider.state('admin', {
  templateUrl: 'path/to/admin/html/template.html',    
  controller: 'adminCtrl',
  resolve: {
    users: function(healthTrackerFactory){
      return healthTrackerFactory.getUsers()
          .then(function(response){
              return response.results;
          });
    }
  }
});
```

then in your controller:

```
app.controller('adminCtrl', function($scope, $location, users){
    $scope.user = users;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the button method worked. Im curious about the $stateProvider method, going to try that as well. thanks again

Comment: if you need to use the list of users in the View without the app user clicking a button, moving it to the state provider section is the best way imho.

Comment: one question about stateProvider... would that replace routeProvider as well?

Comment: yes, see http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router, but not necessary since routeProvider also has `resolve` property: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider. Resolve block is used to make sure that promises or async operations are completed before new view is shown to the user.

Comment: That worked out perfectly. I checked out the stateProvider module, but as you stated, since the resolve property is also available with routeProvider, I stayed with it. Thanks again, solved my issue